# drawBitmap() draws the false part

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm trying to show part of an image in an `ImageView`. I tried it with `canvas.drawBitmap()` but it seems like the false part of the image is displayed. My code:

MainActivity:

```
    this.drawCharacter = new DrawCharacter(1);
    this.bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(16, 32, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    this.c = new Canvas(this.bm);
    this.c = this.drawCharacter.drawCharacter(this.c, this.characterBitmap);
    this.bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.bm, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight, isChild());

    this.imgv.setImageBitmap(this.bm);
```

DrawCharacter:

```
[...]
  Paint localPaint = new Paint();
  paramCanvas.drawBitmap(paramBitmap, new Rect(8, 8, 16, 16), new Rect(4, 0, 12, 8), localPaint);
  return paramCanvas;
[...]
```

And at the end some strange part of the image is shown.

Answer (score 1):

In your `drawBitmap()` call, you set the first Rect parameter to 8,8,16,16,  this is the source rectangle from your bitmap to be drawn,  set it to null to draw the entire bitmap.

[see the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

if  you want to apply this bounds according to the initial bitmap scale, you may need to apply the same scale on your src Rectangle. 
(try to remove the scale part, `createScaledBitmap()` to see if your src rectangle is good without the scale ;) )

Comment: I tried that because I just want to show that part (8, 8, 16, 16) and not the whole bitmap